# vim set default to save buffer when TERM signal received

Tags: bash, vim

I use multiple instances of vim.  Currently I use a bash function

```
kv(){ a=($(pgrep vim)); kill ${a[@]}; }
```

to terminate all running instances of vim.  This has the drawback of leaving unsettled .swp files wherever a vim was killed with unsaved changes.  Is there a way to set vim to save its buffers if it is sent a kill signal?

Comment: I have not tried this myself, so I don't whether it will do what you need, but `:help VimLeave` and `:help v:dying` suggest that the VimLeave event is triggered whenever Vim exits, even because of a signal.

Answer (score 2):

You can not specifically trap the TERM signal, but you can "catch" just about any signal that gives Vim a chance to gracefully exit.  See the example in:

```
:help v:dying
```

You can modify the `:echo` command in the example to something like `:wqall` (see "`:help :wqall`").

I do not recommend this, though.  You could easily have a file (over)written when you did not want it to happen.

Comment: I thank you both for your help, and on the strength of those :help items I added

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to save buffers on `VimLeave`. I've tried the code below

```
autocmd VimLeave * :!touch ~/logs/vim-leave
autocmd VimLeave * :wall
```

This code successfully `touch` the file but didn't save buffers. I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/iQ61c415UR8) from a vim mailing list

> Vim calls deathtrap() function, which closes all buffers, 
>   and then calls getout(), in which all autocommands are processed 
>   (BufWinLeave, BufUnLoad, VimLeavePre and finally VimLeave). But by that 
>   time, you can't safe any buffers anymore.
>
> By the time, Vim handles the deadly signal, it won't call unsafe 
>   functions anymore (e.g. allocate memory) so I doubt it will be possible 
>   to achieve what you want.